# How can I get whole html int response when I use scrapy and there is no direct link in a tag

Tags: python, scrapy

From the site address https://www.shinsegae-lnb.com/html/product/wine.html#
I want to get information on each wine. I only know get response in parse function when there is direct link in a tag like `<a href = "asdf/asf/index.html">`,
but in that site there is no direct link in each wine pod,
but there is only `<a href="#"onclick="viewData('2135')">`.
How can I get information inside of each wine.

I only know this way:

```
def parse(self, response):
        books = response.css('article.product_pod')

        for book in books:
            reletive_url = book.css('h3 a ::attr(href)').get()
            
            if 'catalogue/' in reletive_url :
                book_url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/' + reletive_url
            else :
                book_url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/' + reletive_url
            yield response.follow(book_url, callback = self.parse_book_page)
        
        next_page = response.css('li.next a ::attr(href)').get()

        if next_page is not None:
            if 'catalogue/' in next_page :
                next_page_url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/' + next_page
            else :
                next_page_url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/' + next_page
            yield response.follow(next_page_url, callback = self.parse)
```